# Delphi dynamically creating multiple edit components

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need to create multiple edit components but I'm getting into 1 problem.
I need to set width and height into one fixed value.
The problem is that I can't change height, when I do so it doesn't change at all.
The strange thing is that when I change width it works perfect (all edits have the width value that I set in this function).

Here is my code of this function:

```
procedure Tform1.editcreate;

var i,j: integer;
    sud: array [1..9,1..9] of TEdit;

begin
for i:=1 to 9 do
 for j:=1 to 9 do begin
  sud[i][j]:=TEdit.Create(form1);
  sud[i][j].Height:=50;
  sud[i][j].Width:=50;
  sud[i][j].top:=50*i;
  sud[i][j].left:=50*j;
  sud[i][j].Parent:=form1;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: FYI you should replace "form1" with "self" ;o)

Comment: The first thing you should do with a new form is delete the global form variable. Then it's not possible to make that mistake.

Comment: You do realize that the code you've posted makes no sense, right? The `sud` array is local to the procedure `editCreate`, so at the final `end;` of the procedure it goes out of scope and no longer exists. This means that the entire declaration of the array and addition of the edits into it are nothing but a waste of code lines. (I'm also trying not to picture the user interface you're creating with *81 edit controls* on the same form.)

Comment: I put it here just to see what variable it is, normally I have it declared as form variable.

Comment: Your question says "Here is my code of this function.". I guess it's not really, then. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the height of a single line edit control is determined automatically by the font metrics. So, if you want your edit to be larger, either:

1. Make its font larger, or
2. Set `AutoSize` to be `False`.

I think an edit control with `AutoSize` set to `False` will just look odd due to the extra unused vertical space. I don't think I've ever used, or even seen, an edit control so configured.